# Time synchronisation between devices that connect over UART and Ethernet

Tags: time, synchronization, uart, ethernet

[I have 3 devices which are connected to each other](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mSVR.png)

I wanted to know if there are any existing standards for the Device 1,2 and 3 in the picture to synchronize time.
The IEEE802.1AS (gPTP) can be used between device 2 and 3, but does it work for devices that are connected over UART too?

Comment: Hi.  Your question is not [on-topic for Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).  You may get better results asking it on another site in the Stack Exchange network, such as [Super User](https://superuser.com/) or [Internet of Things](https://iot.stackexchange.com/).  Thanks.

Comment: It can, just not so reliably. As a first approximation you may switch UART into SLIP or PPP mode and use the same way as Ethernet, I.e. via IP protocols.